# Emailing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send a email in Laravel. It works finicky to say at least.  got couple of classes for sending email for different conditions. Only difference would be markup of sent email and blade file which data is sent to before sending. I tried using `use Mail;` in controller from whom i'm sending it, with `\Mail::(...` and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;` with `Mail::(...` and vice-versa. So it ain't it.

Here are the mail files:

ToHR file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\User;

class toHR extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $job;
    public $jobCount;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user,$job,$jobCount)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->jobCount = $jobCount;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.toHR');
    }
}
```

ToHRFirst file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\User;

class toHRFirst extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $job;
    public $jobCount;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user,$job,$jobCount)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->jobCount = $jobCount;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.toHRFirst');
    }
}
```

And my test file JobCreated:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\User;

class JobCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $job;
    public $jobCount;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user,$job,$jobCount)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->jobCount = $jobCount;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.job-created');
    }
}
```

They'll all the same, yet error occurs. What gives? Did i miss something? Any help will be appreciated, just point me in the right direction.

Code which i use to send email:
Variables used get values from queries which are rather long, but they are not an issue anyways.

Ver1:

```
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(

            new JobCreated($user,$job,$jobCount)

        );
```

Ver2:

```
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(

            new toHRFirst($user,$job,$jobCount)

        );
```

Ver3:

```
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(

            new toHR($user,$job,$jobCount)

        );
```

Sending works if it's used first version. Other cannot be found and that's the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your files to follow Laravel convention;

You can see that the file `JobCreated` has a `class JobCreated`. You need to respect the uppercases:

- Rename the `ToHR.php` file into `ToHr.php`, then:
- Rename the class `class toHR`into `class ToHr`
- Rename the `ToHRFirst.php` file into `ToHrfirst.php`, then:
- Rename the class `class toHRFirst` into `class ToHrfirst`

---

Or if you want to keep the uppercases, just rename the classes like so:

- `class toHR`into `class ToHR`
- `class toHRFirst`into `class ToHRFirst`

---

Finally, don't forget to import your job class at the top of your controller file (or wherever you use the Mail method:

`use App\Mail\ToHR;`

and

`use App\Mail\ToHRFirst;`

Comment: Tried renaming. Still throws `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ToHR' not found` And other renaming examples, this just latest one.

Comment: At the top of your controller file, you must import the job class like so: `use App\Mail\ToHR`

Comment: Yeah, not to be ungrateful, i just noticed that. Just switched to SO tab to answer that. I swear, most of my mistakes in last couple of days are caused by lack of sleep. Nonetheless, i'll mark your answer as correct one since comments can't be marked as solutions. Mucho kudos for noticing!

Comment: I have made the same kind of mistakes many times. The answer was in the error message, but sometimes we forget to read it properly! :)